# C# .net: add image to list and show on form

Tags: c#, .net

I am creating a list of pets and I am trying to add photos for each pet. I have the list working but I have never wrked with images in c# before so I am little stuck.

so far I have breed classes(tabby, Siamese, husky and chiwawa) that inherit from a super pet class. Here are the attribute in the pet class:

> string name, long chip, DateTime arrivalDate, Boolean adoptedStatus,
>   Image image

In my main code file I create some new pets and then add them to a pet list:

```
Tabby newTabby1 = new Tabby("sunshine", 22222222222222222, new DateTime(2016, 2, 24), false, Image.FromFile("images/sunshine.jpg"));

Chiwawa newChi1 = new Chiwawa("tony", 33333333333333333, new DateTime(2016, 2, 24), false, Image.FromFile("images/chi.jpg"));

Siamese newsia1 = new Siamese("felix", 44444444444444444, new DateTime(2016, 3, 11), false, Image.FromFile("images/felix.jpg"));

Husky newHusk1 = new Husky("fluffs", 55555555555555555, new DateTime(2016, 2, 24), false, Image.FromFile("images/husky.jpg"));


List<Pet> list = new List<Pet>();
            list.Add(newTabby1);
            list.Add(newChi1);
            list.Add(newsia1);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("list item " + item.Chip );
                builder.Append(item.name + " " + item.Chip + " " + item.arrivalDate + " status" + item.adoptedStatus).Append("\n");


            }
            string result = builder.ToString(); // Get string from StringBuilder
            petList.Text = result;
```

I have an images folder in my project file with the pet photos in jpg format. I am not sure how to get the photos to show up in my list next to the other attributes like name. I am also not sure if I am putting the photos in correctly when I am creating the pets ex: (Image.FromFile("images/husky.jpg").

here is my pet class as well:

```
 public abstract class Pet
    {

        #region Fields
        protected long chip;
        protected DateTime ArrivalDate;
        public string name;
        protected bool AdoptedStatus;
        public static int petCount = 0;
        public Image image;

        #endregion End of Fields

        #region Constructors 
        public Pet()
        {
            chip = 0;
            AdoptedStatus = false;
            petCount++;
        }
        public Pet(string name, long chip, DateTime arrivalDate, Boolean adoptedStatus, Image image)
        {
            this.chip = chip;
            ArrivalDate = arrivalDate;
            AdoptedStatus = adoptedStatus;
            this.name = name;
            petCount++;
            this.image = image;
        }
        #endregion End of Constructors

        #region Properties



        public int PetCount
        {
            get
            {
                return petCount;
            }
        }
        public long Chip
        {
            get
            {
                return chip;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value > 0)
                    chip = value;
                else
                    chip = 0;
            }
        }

        public DateTime arrivalDate { get; set; }



        public Boolean adoptedStatus { get; set; }



        #endregion End Properties

        #region Methods

        public bool UpdateStatus() => adoptedStatus = true;
        public int UpdateInventory() => petCount = petCount - 1;
        public abstract void Noise();

        // public override string ToString()
        // {
        //     return $"{Model}\n MRSP:${Mrsp}\n Vin:{Vin}\n Delivered:{DeliveryDate}\n Sold: {soldStatus}\n";
        //  }
        #endregion End of Methods
    }
```

Comment: How do you display the list on your form?

Comment: @PepitoSh I display it with petList.Text

Comment: Please post a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), meaning that you should also include your `Pet` classes and the code that is used to display your Pets. At the moment we don't even know which GUI-Toolkit (i.e WinForms or WPF) you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If the *images* folder is within your bin/Debug or bin/Release file (depending on your configuration), then you need to use/add Application.StartupPath property to reference the working directory of your application (i.e. Bin/Debug or Bin/Release depending on your configuration).

```
string primaryDir = Application.StartupPath + "/images";
```

Comment: from what I understand, that's not the problem. The code shows the images bing imported (succesfully?) already. The problem, how I've understood it, is how to display said image (what code-statement is needed).

Comment: My answer stemmed from the problem statement: "_I am also not sure if I am putting the photos in correctly when I am creating the pets ex:_"

Comment: That's still only a  partial response.. Probably more fitting as a comment until OP updates the question with a form-example so a complete answer can be given ..

Comment: yep I guess, but in any case, he may just want to try to use the said property if he is stumbled at first in referencing the location of his images, which in my guess, is within the application/executable folder.

Answer (score 0):

what is your front code? how do you want to display the images?